# Kafka Stream - Output to multiple topics ( success and failure topic)

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Can I convert an input message into multiple messages (involving replicating the input message and adding variable content based on a json array element in the message).

If the replicating and adding variable content goes through for some of the elements in json array, it should go to success topic. However if for any of the array element, the processing fails, the message should go to failure topic for retry.

Is this possible to achieve with Kafka streams?

Comment: `if for any of the array element, the processing fails` - what exactly do you mean by processing fails? is it your custom processing logic during `.map()` invocation, or errors on producer side (e.g. by some reason we were not able to deliver message)? and do you need in that case produce all multiple messages (flat mapped) into failure topic, or only some of them that are failed?
 
for converting a single message into multiple, you could use `.flatMapValues(..)`, and for splitting traffic into success or failure topic - you could use `.branch(..)` or `.split(..)` methods.